# Remove parent array

Tags: arrays

I have this array that I generate dynamically. 
But I would like to delete de 'wrapper' array.
How can I do it?

```
Array ( 
               [0] => Array ( 
                    [taxonomy] => city
                    [terms] => Array ( [0] => boston ) 
                    [field] => slug 
                    [operator] => NOT IN 
                ) 
                [1] => Array ( 
                    [taxonomy] => city 
                    [terms] => Array ( [0] => chicago ) 
                    [field] => slug 
                    [operator] => NOT IN 
                ) 
            )
```

How can I remove the parent array to have only this structure:?

```
[0] => Array ( 
                        [taxonomy] => city
                        [terms] => Array ( [0] => boston ) 
                        [field] => slug 
                        [operator] => NOT IN 
                    ) 
                    [1] => Array ( 
                        [taxonomy] => city 
                        [terms] => Array ( [0] => chicago ) 
                        [field] => slug 
                        [operator] => NOT IN 
                    )
```

Comment: if you don't have the wrapper then they are just 2 separated arrays, both with the index as 0 if you dont specify anything else.

Comment: I want to have the index 0 and index 1, because after I will do: $args['tax_query'] = array('post_type' => 'post','relation' => 'AND', $argst); Where $argst must have the two arrays.

Comment: how can `$argst`, a single variable have two separate arrays?

Comment: foreach ($cb_cities as $cb_city) {
     
     $argst[] = wp_parse_args(array('taxonomy' => 'city','terms'=>array($cb_city),'field' => 'slug','operator' => 'NOT IN'));
   }

Comment: you should paste your full code and what you intentd to do instead of just the arrays. We will come to a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that and pretend both arrays belong to the same variable.

The only thing similar you could do is just:

```
$array1 = array ( 
                    'taxonomy' => 'city',
                    'terms' => array ('boston'), 
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN' 
                )

$array2 = array ( 
                    'taxonomy' => 'city',
                    'terms' => array ('chicago'), 
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN' 
                )
```

But you can't hold 2 values in 1 variable.

One variable can only hold ONE value at a time. When you need more values inside one variable then you use arrays and wrap those values together, so that variable is still holding only 1 value, which holds various values grouped together.

Think of the variable as one arm. There's a man with only 1 arm. He wants to buy basketballs, but he can only carry 1 ball. If he need more balls he will need to use a bag (array) to hold those basketballs.

Comment: Ok.And how could I do: $args['tax_query'] = array('post_type' => 'post','relation' => 'AND', $array1, $array2); Dynamically? I could have arrayN